# How do I determine the newest created file in a directory on a linux machine?

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to figure out a way to determine the most recent file created in a directory. I cannot use a module and I am on a Linux OS.

Comment: can you use `glob` and `stat`?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1030401)

Comment: Linux filesystems do not store the birth time of files. This is a question impossible to answer. You can get the modification or the inode change time, but neither of those is the same as the birth time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a simple google gave me good answer

```
@list = `ls -t`;
$newest = $list[0];
```

or  completely in perl

```
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$DIR/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
```

$sorted_files[0] is the most-recently modified. If it isn't the actual
file-of-interest, you can iterate through @sorted_files until you find
the interesting file(s).

Answer (score 2):

No you can not get the files on the basis of their birth date, as their is no linux command to get the birth date of a file, but of-course you can get the access, modification and change information about the file. To get the access, modification and change time information of any file use this :

```
stat file-name
```

Also, to get the most recent changed/modified file use this:

```
ls -ltr | tail -1
```

Comment: How exactly would I put that in a code? For example, the files are stored in the default $_ variable and I want to type a code to only print the newest file.

Comment: just put the below code `my $newestFile=\`ls -ltr | tail -1\`` and it will store the newest file(in the same directory in which the program is running) name in the variable $newestFile.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd DIR
ls -l -rt | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The naughty [`IO::All`](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) method: `;-)`

```
use IO::All; 
use v5.20;

# sort files by their modification time and store in an array:
my @files = sort{$b->mtime <=> $a->mtime} io(".")->all_files; 
# get the first/newest file from the sort: 
say "$files[0] ". ~~localtime($files[0]->mtime);
```